# Using a python menchanize response as a dict

Tags: python, mechanize, mechanize-python

When open a link with mechanize:

```
r = br.open(url)
print(r.read())
```

the returned results is something like:

```
[{"name":"NAME","year":"2000","link":"LINK"}]
```

How can I convert this response into a dict so I can access it later. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load it with [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module:

```
import json 

data = json.load(r)
```

Note that you don't need to call `read()` explicitly, `load()` would do that for you.